# A basic crawler/scraper that can provide all URLs under a parent URL

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

Given a parent URL (say "http://dir.yahoo.com/News_and_Media/"), I want to scrape all URLs which are on this page and till depth X.

I don't want to move to another domain even if depth criteria forces it to do that. Ex. While going for "http://dir.yahoo.com/News_and_Media/" i don't want to go to the depth 2 which is not under "dir.yahoo.com".

There must be some tool available for this thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Specifically you would want these command line options in your case:

```
$ wget -r http://www.example.com/ -l X
```

where obviously you would replace "http://www.example.com/" with the URL of your choosing and "X" with the depth you want.

Comment: It was really a great and simple answer! The only issue I face is that a few websites block wget recursive even after using WAIT option. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to set a user-agent to disguise `wget`. A simple `wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0" [...]` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

try [winhttrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

Comment: Considering that I am fine with parsing output of winhttptrack to extract URLs.

winhttrack will download complete web as end urls are urls like 'facebook.com' and it will take dump of this url as well.

I don't know if it accepts depth option.

Comment: there is a depth option (http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html)
Limits options:
  rN set the mirror depth to N (* r9999) (--depth[=N])

Comment: What if I don't want to go to other websites? (Eg. Links to external websites are available at various stages).
Any idea about the difference between rN and %eN?

Comment: for other websites, check the scan rules. 
Put -* and +<your domain name>*
i think httrack is really flexible, but u need to do some read up and testing to get it to work properly. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for some rule which will constrain it to dir.yahoo.com domain itself. :)